# dd not enough space

Tags: partition, dd, devices, size, clone

I have a drive that is about 1TB big. It is mostly free space. When you add up the size of all the partitions, it is less than 256GB.

I have another drive that is 256GB.

I would like to clone the data from the 1TB drive to the 256GB drive.

Is this possible? Obviously the source is bigger than the destination, but I'm wondering since the 1TB drive is mostly free space and the total of the partitions is less than 256GB.

Right now, I am just getting an error that the drive is out of space.

I have tried it with "conv=sparse" as well as with multiple "bs" sizes including as small as 512.

Source:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953,87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVL21T0HCLR-00BL2              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX

Device              Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048     206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2     206848     239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3     239616  411406335 411166720 196,1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 1999026176 2000406527   1380352   674M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 1997025280 1999026175   2000896   977M Linux swap

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Destination:

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 238,5 GiB, 256087425024 bytes, 500170752 sectors
Disk model: Extreme Pro     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Command Used:

(Note: I have tried many different sets of parameters)

```
sudo dd status=progress bs=512 if=/dev/nvme0n1 of=/dev/sdd
```

Comment: 1. Don't use `dd`. 2. Please provide the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdX` in your question, replacing `sdX` with the names of the relevant old and new devices. 3. Show the exact command you're using

Comment: @roaima - I will do this as soon as I am home.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just copy the files rather than the disk partitions?

Comment: the size of the partitions is < 200 GB, or the used size on the filesystems (i.e. the size of the files there) is < 200 GB? You also didn't show the actual commands you ran when you tried it, so we can't know what you actually tried. Be specific.

Comment: `dd` doesn't care about used/unused space, it copies the whole file/partition/disk/device (whatever, since you haven't shown the command line, who knows what you're trying to do) ... and 1TB > 256GB - therefore the 256GB has no chance of storing 1TB, The `conv=sparse` option does what is documented, and has nothing to do with used/unused space

Comment: @roaima - I added the fdisk outputs

Comment: @ilkkachu - I added the exact command

Comment: @roaima - I absolutely could copy the files and that is what I do now. I want to be able to clone the drive to another to, for example, boot it on another computer, as a replacement if I mess up my drive, etc.

Comment: Use rsync IMHO to solve this

Comment: Use GUI tool like `gparted` (either as an app installed on your gnu/linux, or as an liveusb) and you'll comprehend why the direct DD approach is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for adding the details.

- As you have Windows installed, be sure you have a current Windows Recovery Media. This USB stick can be created by your Windows. Search for Recovery media in the Windows start menu or just run

  ```
  C:\Windows\System32\RecoveryDrive.exe
  ```

  This will help if your Windows should not boot anymore after the disk change.
- You have a Linux SWAP partition. There are no data of value inside. So this 1 GB can be freed and recreated later on the new media.

---

You are copying the whole SSD (1TB) to a smaller one. The amount of contained data would fit as the partitions in total have a smaller size than the destination SSD.

The problem are the last partitions. They are located at the end while the other partitions reside at the beginning, followed by a huge gap.

I would suggest to

1. first move the partitions from the end just tight to the other ones. Then all partitions are below the 250 GB and the whole structure will fit in the space of the new disk.
2. After having moved all partitions to the beginning of the disk you can do your `dd`. you might want to limit the block count to the size of the destination disk to prohibit an error message.

   ```
   dd bs=512 count=500170752 if=/dev/nvme0n1 of=/dev/sdd status=progress
   ```

   Faster would be to limit the count to just behind the last partition. But as you might want to resize/delete some of the partitions, I can't calculate it.
3. Still missing is the Backup GPT Table at the end of the disk. A partition editor will issue an error like
   `The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.`

   Create the Backup GPT Table by

   ```bash
   sudo sgdisk -e /dev/sdd
   ```

   or just open any partition editor and save the partition table.
4. Now you can move the recovery partition back to the end of the disk and you are done.

If you are unsure how to move the partitions, just have a look over to [this answer at SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/a/1804927/1787250). I think `gparted` is a convenient way to manage it safely.

---

*(Thanks @TomYan for the hint with the GPT backup table)*

Comment: FWIW the backup GPT at the end of the source drive will then be missing on destination drive. It may not prevent anything from working on Windows though, and it can easily recovered with `gdisk` (if Windows does not do that automatically). Can also create the GPT on the destination drive manually and clone the partitions one by one instead.

Comment: @TomYan : Thanks for the hint. I updated the answer.